# Why wouldn't you always use 3 fault domains?

Tags: azure

When setting up VM's in Azure you can put them into different fault domains.  You can put them into 1, 2, or 3 fault domains.

Why wouldn't you always put them in 3 fault domains (assuming you have at least 3 VMs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would always do that, but some regions do not support 3 fault domains, only 2. thats the only problem.